# CSS Input (button) Border Specificity

Tags: html, css, border

As I understand it, a class should take precedence in styles over the element styles. I've tried to style `button`, `input[type=button]`, and `input[type=submit]` and noticed that with the `input` (`button` and `submit`), the `border` style from the element would take precedence over the `border` style for the class. I did not notice this behaviour, however, on the `button` element.

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/JVNZv/1/) demonstrating the situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        input[type=button], button {
            border: none;
        }

        .class {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button"  class="class" value="With class" />
    <input type="button" value="Without class" />
    <button class="class">With class</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The above renders like this:

[image]

I've noticed the same behaviour in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome.

Am I doing something wrong? Have I misunderstood specificity in this case? Is this specific to `border` only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're not comparing apples to apples. Attribute selectors have a specificity of `0,1,0` just like classes. However, element selectors have a specificity of `0,0,1`, which makes your first selector of `input[type="button"]` have a specificity of `0,1,1` which is greater than `0,1,0`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

If you wanted them both to have the same specificity, you should use:

```
input.class
input[type="button"]
```

-or-

```
.class
[type="button"]
```

Comment: Add [example comparing 'apples to apples'](http://jsfiddle.net/JVNZv/5/), perhaps? (edit: added better example)

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware that attribute selectors have a higher specificity than element selectors, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

An attribute selector + the element selector have a higher specificity than a simple class selector.

Possible fix:

```
.class, .class[type] {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

this way you can apply the class "class" to any element with a type specified and achieve the results you wanted.